# Is it possible to pass null value when the table is not present in the source database

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, msbi

I am trying to make a Dataflow Task which can be used by various clients. Here I am using two oledb commands to fetch values from two similar tables and ingest it in one staging table. When the client has both the tables, the component works fine. But the problem arises when the client has either one of them.

I did not find any help over internet to do such thing. Can I have a sql query where it sends null when the table is not present in the source or there is any method to resolve it through SSIS itself (as both the oledb commands are present in a single Dataflow Task).

Comment: Maybe check first if the table exists and don't execute task if it doesn't: SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = ?

Comment: As I have written that the task has two oledb commands and the task fails if even one of the table is not present followed by failure of the whole package(which is not affordable). At any cost there will be atleast one table among them, so it needs to be executed to ingest the data in the staging table.

Comment: Split the load into two oledb loads and do a check on each before loading to see if tables exist, merge data after.